# Convert string to array in angular2 in html template

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting Json reponse like this,

```
var optCities = [{
"resultData": {
"Hoteloption": [
    {   
        "CityRating":"[
        {'City': 'Bangkok','Rating':4.5},
        {'City': 'Phuket','Rating':4.5},
        {'City': 'Nonthaburi','Rating':4.5},
        {'City': 'Broc','Rating':4.5}]"
    }]
}}];
```

I've tried to create a pipe

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    var st = JSON.stringify(value);
    var result =  JSON.parse(st);
    return result;
  }
```

first tried to create json object.
but if I console the `result` variable it still shows string.

```
<div *ngFor="let city of optCities[0].resultData.Hoteloption[0].CityRating | strReplace ;let i = index; ">
    {{city.Rating}}
</div>
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: can you create a plunker ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I've created jsfiddle its same what i'm trying 
https://jsfiddle.net/fmqzxwc3/

Comment: try this:

st.json()['resultData'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested object keys should be wrapped in double qoutes instead of single, it is better to fix this from backend, here is some simple solution for do it with JS

Angular pipe

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    // i'm guessing that your data (value) is string
    return typeof value==='string' ? JSON.parse(value.replace(/'/g, '"')) : value;
}
```

Comment: How can I do this in angular2?

Answer (score 1):

you are getting incorrect JSON of CityRating Array from server

here is an workaround
Define the function in your component

```
getJson(x){
  let z = x.replace(/'/g, '"');
  return JSON.parse(z);
}
```

to use in you template

```
<div *ngFor="let city of 
getJson(optCities[0].resultData.Hoteloption[0].CityRating);let i = 
 index; ">
  {{city.Rating}}
</div>
```

the function will return you an vaild JSON Array so your loop will work

Answer (score 0):

That's because your JSON object is wrong. Remove the double quotes from the array in CityRating.

```
var optCities = [{
"resultData": {
"Hoteloption": [
{   
    "CityRating":[
    {'City': 'Bangkok','Rating':4.5},
    {'City': 'Phuket','Rating':4.5},
    {'City': 'Nonthaburi','Rating':4.5},
    {'City': 'Broc','Rating':4.5}]
}]
}}];
```

Comment: that's the problem I can't change that getting it from response of API

Comment: any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maube

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return JSON.parse(value);
}
```

This is if you array really must be in string

Comment: Thats not working, getting Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2